# Why does linux (ARM) always switch to supervisor mode during exception handling?

Tags: linux, arm

During exception handling, Linux always switches to supervisor mode. What is the reason for this?. Why can't it continue execution in the exception mode itself?

Answer (score 3):

When an exception occurs on ARM the processor switches into abort state. While in this state, the processor cannot process any interrupts. This means that screen and network updates cannot happen, nor can there be any pre-emption. For this reason, one should never perform a long running operation in the abort state.

What probably happens (I am not a linux kernel expert), is that the exception is recorded and placed only a queue and the the exception handler immediately returns. The kernel now can re-enable interrupts and process all high priority tasks. It then deals with the exception at its leisure in a way that does not disrupt other tasks.

I have not read [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tasklets/index.html) but it does seem to have the kind of details you are looking for.

Comment: Dorn, Thanks for the explanation. But, my question is more towards linux. All the modes other than "user mode" are previlged. Then , why linux does linux always switch to supervisor mode?

Comment: @Doron You have put a circular link to the same question you are answering :-) :-) :-)

Comment: @OP in short because being in abort mode blocks interrupts so we try to return as quickly as possible. We then need to enter supervisor mode to do the cleanup

Comment: @Doron. By exception, I do not mean only abort. ARM defines exceptions as all those which affects program execution. So, For. E.g., interrupt is an exception. So, when interrupt occurs, ARM switches to IRQ mode. IRQ mode is previleged and have access to all the System resource like supervisor mode. But, even then, Linux branches to supervisor mode.

Comment: for the same reason, when we are in exception mode, the processor is unable to receive other exceptions.

Comment: This is somewhat of an oversimplification.
There is a priority order of exceptions, and higher priority ones can still occur. Moreover, an exception handler can re-enable interrupts (FIQ or IRQ) once it is safe to do so.

I think a simpler explanation of why Linux always switches to SVC is that it was not architected to specifically take advantage of all the modes provided by ARM processors. SVC is what will be entered for system calls anyway, so I guess it just made sense to do everything in there.

Comment: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0013b/index.html, does talk about nested interrupt handlers but even so, the document states the processor must change states before re-enabling interrupts. This is because the new interrupt will overwrite the LR_IRQ making a return impossible.

Answer (score 2):

I might be late to answer in this post. 
Linux kernel implementation has done this way, so that whenever any interrupt occurs in first level IRQ handler, it copies IRQ registers to SVC registers and switch the ARM to SVC mode.

This has been done for two major puporse:

1. you do not need a separate stack for IRQ mode
2. by moving it back to SVC, you may ensure that another Interrupt can be handled while other one is getting served in SVC mode.

Answer (score 0):

You would still need a stack for IRQ mode its just that the stack would be very small as essentially we would only need to store the spsr and lr there...but yes you are right this will help to support neseted interrupt but this is not the only way of doing that..we can switch to system mode (which uses user mode registers) from the interrupt mode and still support nested interrupts